# XSLT logic to add a sequence for the combination of elements with same dates and ID field

Tags: xslt

I am struggling to create logic for transformation.

Logic: "Seq" A sequential number used to make a unique key when the ID and Date fields are equal.

```
<root>
    <Record>
        <ID>11</ID>
        <date>2020-03-11-07:00</date>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>13</ID>
        <date>2020-03-12-07:00</date>
        <quantity>20</quantity>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>15</ID>
        <date>2020-03-13-07:00</date>
        <quantity>40</quantity>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>11</ID>
        <date>2020-03-11-07:00</date>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>13</ID>
        <date>2020-03-17-07:00</date>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
    </Record>
</root>
```

**to, Output**

```
ID,seq,Date,quantity
11,1,2020-03-11-07:00,10
11,2,2020-03-11-07:00,5
13,1,2020-03-12-07:00,20
15,1,2020-03-13-07:00,40
13,1,2020-03-17-07:00,100
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 it is a simple grouping problem with a composite key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:text>ID,seq,Date,quantity&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" composite="yes" group-by="ID, date">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
      <xsl:value-of select="ID, position(), date, quantity" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepy

XSLT 3 can be used with Saxon 9.8 and later or AltovaXML 2017 R3 or later.